# Customizing Border Page

Tags: html, css, border

I need to customize the border of my HTML page.

I really need to learn how to border this style:

[image]

How can I start looking and studying about the customization of these style borders? Is  there any service of this type that I could purchase the html/css code, for example?

What is the name of this border style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look the CSS property "border-image" and at this article. Might lead you closer to your goal. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/

Answer (score 1):

**I know this is closed**, but perhaps this will be useful for someone else.

You could either set an image with a border design as the background.

Or, you could create your own custom border!

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 93vh; /* set to height of page */
}

.corner {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/10/9c/57/109c57355958d296033ee8577491c006.jpg');
  background-repeat: none;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.corner.bottom-right {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.corner.bottom-left {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.corner.top-right {
  transform: scale(-1, -1);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.corner.top-left {
  transform: scale(1, -1);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="border">
    <div class="corner top-left"></div>
    <div class="corner top-right"></div>
    <div class="corner bottom-left"> </div>
    <div class="corner bottom-right"></div>>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9eb3t0v6/)

What this solution does:

- Sets a border around the entire page with `.border`, you can change the color, width, etc here
- Sets a corner image in `.corner` under `background-image`, this should just be one corner of the border which we will rotate to suit, this would look something like this: [Image Corner Example](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/10/9c/57/109c57355958d296033ee8577491c006.jpg)
- Sets the position of the corner image to `absolute`, so it will appear exactly where we tell it to, in this case in each of the corners, the size of the corner image is also set in `.corner`
- Each of the images has a unique position tag as part of the `class` tag, these are of the form `bottom-right` and dictate where they're going to be on the page
- Dictating the position via the class `bottom-right` is done using these respective tags `bottom: 0; right: 0;` which correspond to where we want it to be on the page
- Dictating the direction we want the image facing happens with this tag `transform: scaleX(-1)`, read more on transform here: [Transform](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)

I hope this is useful for someone! :)

Comment: I have no words!! Thanks! The main thing to study about is the `.corner`right?

Comment: If you like the design, all you need to change is the corner image here: `background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/10/9c/57/109c57355958d296033ee8577491c006.jpg');` [Image](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/10/9c/57/109c57355958d296033ee8577491c006.jpg)

Comment: I've done up a description of what happens in my code in my updated answer, hopefully this clarifies things!